# Slide animation using jqwicket

Tags: java, jquery, wicket

I have some basic knowledge using jqwicket. It's prety straightforward but I have problem implementing this slide animation: http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/rWbFw/

Animation is the simple part, but I don't know how to include custom function for resizing:

```
var utils = {
maskWidth : $('#mask').width(),
currIndex : 0,
setWidths : function(){
    //setting maskWidth
    utils.maskWidth = $('#mask').width();

    //setting wrapper width 
    $('#wrapper').css('width',$('.full').length * utils.maskWidth);

    //setting 'full div' width
    $('.full').each(function(index){
        $(this).css('width',utils.maskWidth);
    });

    //setting curr wrapper margin (for window resize)
    $('#wrapper').css('margin-left',-(utils.currIndex*utils.maskWidth));

}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add your JavaScript to the `<head>` tag. Create a `Behavior` and override its `renderHead(Component, IHeaderResponse)`.

`IHeaderResponse` has several handy methods for appending to head